# How to make string a palindrome with minimum number of shifts?

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

I am given a string for example `aaabb` and i have to make it a palindrome with minimum number of shifts,what algorithm should i use to achieve that?
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/sample-1-1/challenges/cyclic-palindrome

Please no code only algorithm

Comment: @templatetypedef nothing,becuase i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: 1) implement a shift function. 2) implement a palindrome check function. 3) figure out how to check shifts in both directions at the same time (or just check all possible shifts). 4) put it all together and submit. That's not the most efficient solution, but it is a pretty obvious and simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Idea 1:

You can use polynomial hashing to compute the hash of the shifted string in `O(1)` using the prefix sums of hashes for the initial string and for its reversed version. After that, you need to check that these two hashes are equal. You can just test all possible shifts and choose the smallest one that fits (the total time complexity is `O(N)`).

Idea 2:

Let's write the string twice. We need to find a palindrome of at least `N` characters. You can use Manacher's algorithm to find all such palindromes in linear time and choose the one that corresponds to the smallest shift.

Both solution have a linear time complexity, but the first one is slightly easier to code, while the second one is guaranteed to work for all possible inputs as it doesn't rely on lack of hash collisions.

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on both of those. It's nice when you can actually use a [so] answer as is to understand how to do something rather than having to go read up on some other stuff or do a whole lot of analysis yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing to notice in palindrome string is there can be at most 1 type of character with odd frequency. i.e., abcccba a(2) b(2) c(3).
So while scanning string, maintain count of characters. If odd_count > 1, print -1
If odd_count = 1, you need to keep this type of character in middle, so shift string minimum times (either left or right shift) and check if it forms palindrome.
If odd_count = 0, you need to shift and check.